# Stack exchange for aerospace engineering

Tags: discussion

I am not sure whether it is, but I hope this is the right place to bring up such a topic.

I would like to hear the communities opinion on starting an Aerospace StackExchange aimed at the science and engineering behind the Aerospace field.

Such a StackExchange will deal with topics such as:

- Aerodynamics
- Flight mechanics
- Flight performace
- Aero structures
- Space flight
- Rockets
- Satelites
- CFD
- FEM
  etc.

Many questions relevant to this topic have been asked and very well answered in this Aviation StackExchange and many of these questions and others from other StackExchanges will be able to be migrated to the Aerospace Exchange.

Please don't judge me to harshly if this is not the correct place for this discussion, I will appreciate it if you can then point me in the direction of the place to discuss new StackExchanges.

Otherwise, I will be glad to hear any opinions of my idea.

Comment: [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is where formal proposals for new stacks are made, although getting some feedback here is definitely a good idea. I think that in order to justify an aerospace site you would need to clearly explain what it would include that isn't already covered by aviation.SE and space.SE.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think an aerospace engineering site is necessary. Just about any question under the aero part of the category would be on topic here, and as you noted, we already have a lot of those questions answered here. Just about any question under the space part of the category would be on topic over at the [Space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) site (also in beta). Even without those sites, the questions would still be on topic at the general [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) site (also in beta).

So it seems to me that any questions on that topic would already be on topic on possibly two sites. The space and air sides are also different enough that I'm not sure it would make sense to combine them. I don't know if there would be enough traffic for the topic to have its own separate site.

As [Pondlife](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/stack-exchange-for-aerospace-engineering#comment1232_1630) noted, you an always go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and create a proposal. Part of the process is working out the scope of the site and gauging interest.